# conditional diff,divide on one same column of a data-frame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi Hoping to get some help, I have a Dataframe df like this:

```
label   cell_name hour  kpi1    kpi2
train   c1  1   10  20
train   c1  2   10  44
train   c1  3   11  33
train   c1  4   5   1
train   c1  5   2   6
test    c1  1   78  66
test    c1  2   45  2
test    c1  3   23  12
test    c1  4   65  45
test    c1  5   86  76
```

My intention is to conditionally subtract some value lets say(50) from kpi1,kpi2 columns of the test set and divide the same columns with a train set(groupby cell & hour) and attach this to the original data frame so the new column would look like;

```
label   cell_name hour  kpi1    kpi2    kpi1_index  kpi2_index
train   c1  1   10  20      
train   c1  2   10  44      
train   c1  3   11  33      
train   c1  4   5   1       
train   c1  5   2   6       
test    c1  1   78  66   2.8         0.8
test    c1  2   45  2    -0.5       -1.09
test    c1  3   23  12  -2.45       -1.15
test    c1  4   65  45    3          -5
test    c1  5   86  76    18        4.33
```

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
rr=os.getcwd()
df=pd.read_excel(rr+'\\KPI_test_train.xlsx')
print(df.columns)


def f(x,y):
    return ((x-50)/y)     
df_grouped = df.groupby(['label'])
[dtest,dtrain]=[y for x,y in df_grouped]
dtest=dtest.groupby(['label','cell_name','hour']).sum()
dtrain=dtrain.groupby(['label','cell_name','hour']).sum()

for i in dtest.columns:
    dtest[i+'_index']=f(dtest[i],dtrain[i])
```

the function f returns NaN values for all rows.
but this is kind of nasty, considering how nice pandas usually is at these things. What's the built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion here is better working with each `DataFrame` separately - so first filter by condition with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, create `MultiIndex` by columns for align and apply formula for all values. Then add [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `test` DataFrame and last if need one DataFrame use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
lab = df.pop('label')
dtest = df[lab.eq('train')].set_index(['cell_name','hour'])
dtrain = df[lab.eq('test')].set_index(['cell_name','hour'])

df = dtest.join(((dtrain - 50) / dtest).add_suffix('_index'))

df = (pd.concat([dtrain, df], keys=('train','test'), sort=False)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_0':'label'}))
print (df)
   label cell_name  hour  kpi1  kpi2  kpi1_index  kpi2_index
0  train        c1     1    78    66         NaN         NaN
1  train        c1     2    45     2         NaN         NaN
2  train        c1     3    23    12         NaN         NaN
3  train        c1     4    65    45         NaN         NaN
4  train        c1     5    86    76         NaN         NaN
5   test        c1     1    10    20    2.800000    0.800000
6   test        c1     2    10    44   -0.500000   -1.090909
7   test        c1     3    11    33   -2.454545   -1.151515
8   test        c1     4     5     1    3.000000   -5.000000
9   test        c1     5     2     6   18.000000    4.333333
```